# JavaSctript Promise.all on map

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a function that retrieves a list of vehicles from DB.
This needs to be mapped over, sending another request for each of those vehicles.
Results are then pushed over to the array.

My issue is that I need to be able to wait until all vehicles were looped over and until the bucketStopVehcilesPosition gathers all the data. Then continue with other code.

I am failing at this as map function finishes quicker and does not care about the second request to the DB. I eventually retrieve those but the code is already completed. So console.log produces an empty array.

This is not the first time I encounter this issue. Does anyone have any pattern solution for this kind of problem?

Thank you so much for your advice.

```
AdminTable.getStopVehiclesPosition()
    .then((result) => {
      return Promise.all(result.map((item) => {
        AdminTable.getLatestPosition({vehicleId: item.vehicleId})
        .then((data) => {
          bucketStopVehiclesPosition.push({ 
            vehicleId: item.vehicleId,
            plateNumber: item.plateNumber,
            lat: data.position.coords.lat,
            lon: data.position.coords.long,
            heading: data.position.coords.heading,
            speed: data.position.coords.speed
          }) 
        })
      }))
      .then(() => {
        console.log(bucketStopVehiclesPosition)
      })
    })
```

Comment: `return AdminTable...` or remove `{}` around arrow body.

Comment: you have to **return** something in the map `return AdminTable.getLatestPosition`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko post it as answer? :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `reduce` if you want to sequentially resolve your promises. `map` is synchronous.

```js
    AdminTable.getStopVehiclesPosition()
      .then((result) =>
        result.reduce( async (previousPromise, item) => {
          await previousPromise;
          return AdminTable.getLatestPosition({vehicleId: item.vehicleId})
                  .then((data) => {
                    bucketStopVehiclesPosition.push({ 
                      vehicleId: item.vehicleId,
                      plateNumber: item.plateNumber,
                      lat: data.position.coords.lat,
                      lon: data.position.coords.long,
                      heading: data.position.coords.heading,
                      speed: data.position.coords.speed
                    }) 
                  });
        }, Promise.resolve())  
      );
```

Comment: It's not answering the question. OP was not asking for sequential resolving.

Comment: But it's not possible to resolve those promises at once. You need to sequentially resolve it so that you can push the output. That's why he put this on his question:

"I am failing at this as map function finishes quicker and does not care about the second request to the DB. I eventually retrieve those but the code is already completed. So console.log produces an empty array"

Comment: You can map them to an array of promises and resolve them with `Promise.all` as Yury has mentioned in the comment. The problem is the code is mapping to `undefined` at the moment, as the promise returned by `AdminTable.getLatestPosition()` is not returned in the `map` function.

Comment: Ahh I get your point. Yeah the first comment is correct. He didn't return the 4th line. Thanks

Comment: The answer is still correct, just not answering what was asked :)

Comment: Surething mate. No biggie :D